# Using onchange to update dynamically created field

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have the following code which is supposed to pass the total price value as quantity * price per unit, but is not working.

```
aTextBox3.onchange = function() { 
    alert(prueba); 
    for (var i=0;i<myLength;i++) { 
        //form.precio.value = valor_total; 
        form.precio[i].value = form.cantidad[i].value * form.preciounitario[i].value; 
    } 
};
```

http://contabilidad-general.es/app/add-detailed-invoice-fields.php

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is a little short on details, could you provide the problematic code (the relevant parts only), and elaborate on "is not working"?

Comment: If that link (presumably point to the code you are referring to, although this is not 100% clear) goes dead, this question **and** any answers it might have loose all of their value. On the other hand with any of the two  correct answers of the form "Yes someone can help" or "No, nobody can help" not much is lost. Do want to know if someone can help you or do you want a solution?

Comment: I have ater the code the code.

Comment: aTextBox3.onchange = function() { 

alert(prueba);
for (var i=0;i<myLength;i++) {
//form.precio.value = valor_total;
form.precio[i].value = form.cantidad[i].value * form.preciounitario[i].value;
}
};

Comment: That onchange event is not referencig the created fields.